# Not able to add the Firewall rule in Google compute Instance through Terraform Script

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

[enter image description here][1]I am trying to add the http and https firewall rules in compute engine instance through terraform script. But it is not reflecting in the console.

This the script I used:

```
resource "google_compute_firewall" "allow-http" {
  name    = "allow-http"
  network = "default"

  allow {
    protocol = "tcp"
    ports    = ["80"]
  }

  source_ranges = ["0.0.0.0/0"]  # Allow traffic from any source IP (update as needed)
}
```

After creating a new instance using the terraform script, it is still not reflecting.
Also added the tags and target tags too.
Attaching the screenshot.

I am expecting the Firewall rules to be turned on when i run the script in terraform.

Let me share the complete script and configuration :

```
  resource "google_compute_instance" "web-terraform" {
  name         = "web-terraform"
  machine_type = "n1-standard-2"
  zone         = "us-central1-a"
  tags = ["http-server","https-server", "allow-redis"]
   
  boot_disk {
    initialize_params {
      image = "ubuntu-os-cloud/ubuntu-2004-lts"
    }
  }

  network_interface {
    network = "default"
     access_config {
    // Ephemeral public IP
    }
  }
  metadata_startup_script = <<-EOF
  apt update
  apt install -y redis-server
  systemctl enable redis-server
  systemctl start redis-server
  mkdir -p /var/www
  echo "Hello!!." > /var/www/index.html
  nohup python3 -m http.server 80 --directory /var/www &
  EOF

  service_account {
    email  = "myserviceaccount.name"
    scopes = ["cloud-platform"]
  }

}

resource "google_compute_firewall" "default" {
  name    = "allow-http"
  network = google_compute_network.default.name
  
  allow {
    protocol = "icmp"
  }

  allow {
    protocol = "tcp"
    ports    = ["80", "443"]
  }

  source_tags = ["allow-http"]
}

resource "google_compute_network" "default" {
  name = "allow-https"
}


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/36yio.png
```

Comment: Please share the instance config

Comment: I provided the full configuration details/script now. Please check and let me know

Comment: Thanks for checking Fabio, I found the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for checking on this. I've found the answer and would like to share it with you for your benefit.

We have to make sure to give the correct name for the firewall to be turned on in the compute instance.
Make sure to use the target tags. It will help turn on the http and https traffic firewall rules.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3EUq.png)

```
resource "google_compute_firewall" "default-allow-http" {
name    = "default-allow-http"
network = "default"

  allow {
  protocol = "tcp"
  ports    = ["80"]
   }

 source_ranges = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
 target_tags = ["http-server"]
```

}

```
resource "google_compute_firewall" "default-allow-https" {
name    = "default-allow-https"
network = "default"

allow {
protocol = "tcp"
ports    = ["443"]
}

source_ranges = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
target_tags = ["https-server"]
}
```

}